# __func__ or __FUNCTION__ or manual const char* id?

Tags: c

I'm wondering how widely are `__func__` (part of C99, but I'm compiling as C89) and `__FUNCTION__` supported.

I have an old code base that is mostly using manual `const char* id;` variables that are then passed to various (mostly logging) functions. I would like to get rid of this and move the function name into a macro.

Comment: Check the boost [current_function.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/current_function.hpp) header. I know you're asking this for C, and you can't use that header directly. But nevertheless, looking at the `#define`s gives a good idea of what compilers support which methods of getting the current function.

Comment: @Sander That kind of qualifies as an answer. Could you make it into one?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would answer your question, but I guess you've cleared up that doubt. Posted the same as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The boost [current_function.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/current_function.hpp) header contains several `#define`s for the ways to get the current function on different platforms.

That's not to say that those platforms don't support other ways of getting the current function, but the choices made for boost are likely to represent nice (if not the nicest) ways of getting the information on those platforms.

An adaptation of this header for your code (and for C) could well be what you need.

Answer (score 23):

The predefined identifier `__func__` was added to the 1999 ISO C standard; the older 1990 C standard doesn't have it.

Support for `__func__` in pre-C99 compilers will depend on which compiler you're using.

Modern versions of gcc support `__func__` even in C90 mode (`-ansi` or `-std=c89`).

Before `__func__` was added to the standard, gcc implemented its own equivalent extension, but with the name `__FUNCTION__`. (gcc also supports `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which is identical to `__func__` and `__FUNCTION__` for C, but provides more information in C++.)

The [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Function-Names.html) gives some advice:

> `__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`. Older versions of GCC recognize only this name. However, it is not standardized. For maximum
>   portability, we recommend you use `__func__`, but provide a fallback
>   definition with the preprocessor:

```
 #if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
 # if __GNUC__ >= 2
 #  define __func__ __FUNCTION__
 # else
 #  define __func__ "<unknown>"
 # endif
 #endif
```

which implies that gcc added support for `__FUNCTION__` in version 2. gcc 2.0 [was released](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) in 1992; you're very unlikely to be using a version of gcc that doesn't support at least `__FUNCTION__`, if not `__func__`.

Note that since `__func__` and `__FUNCTION__` are predefined identifiers, not macros, you only need the `#define` once, not in each function. On the other hand, you can't use `#ifdef __func__` or `#ifdef __FUNCTION__` to detect the level of support.

As for other compilers, a quick experiment indicates that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express supports `__FUNCTION__`, but not `__func__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, when compiling C code. The above block of code from the gcc manual compiles under MSVC, but it results in `__func__` being defined as `"<unknown>"`. It shouldn't be too difficult to adjust it to recognize that MSVC supports `__FUNCTION__`. (I don't know whether older versions do so.) You can probably use the predefined macro `_MSC_VER` for this. [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says that support for `__FUNCTION__` goes back at least to the 2003 release, which sets `_MSC_VER` to `1300`, so changing the second line to

```
# if __GNUC >= 2 || _MSC_VER >= 1300
```

is a good start. (It may well have been supported in earlier releases.)

For compilers other than gcc and MSVC, you'll have to consult their respective documentation -- but in any case, the block of code recommended in the gcc manual should work for any compiler, at worst falling back to `"<unknown>"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is regardless what C standard is used (if C89 or C99). The more important factor is the compiler being used since it is the one that will implement `__func__`. The latest GCC compilers will add `__func__` no matter the standard being used. I think. :)

Comment: No, `__func__` was added by C99; it doesn't exist in C89/C90. But gcc does support it for all versions of the standard.